# Authorising team city build agents automatically in the cloud

Tags: teamcity, rackspace-cloud

We use rackspace as our cloud provider and spin up new build agents as and when needed from existing server images.

Team city then detects the build agent image but does not authorise it automatically.

Can you tell me how to authorise the build agents without the need to manually go to team city and click authorise as these servers can spin up different flavors, each with different config.

Do I just need to write the correct authorisation key to the build agent config file or is there a better approach to using team city with cloud servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that worked for me was to store the unique authorisation code that is written to the build agent config file and then pass this into the team city build step. The build step then updates the build agent config file using powershell and the build agent is authorised, when it next communicates with the team city server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?

Comment: yes please ... I won't vote up since it doesn;t actually tell you how

Answer (score 3):

In TeamCity 10 you can use the [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-Agents) to authorise the agent on startup using an admin username/password:

```
curl -sS -X PUT --data "true" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -u ${TEAMCITY_SERVER_USERNAME}:${TEAMCITY_SERVER_PASSWORD} ${TEAMCITY_SERVER_URL}/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/${TEAMCITY_AGENT_NAME}/authorized
```

If you tail the `BuildAgent/logs/teamcity-agent.log` file you will see a `Registered` message and then after that you can run the above command.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I have just adapted the values for wget (the principle is the same).

    wget --user "" --password "<admin token here>" --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --method=PUT --body-data=true -qO - "${TEAMCITY_SERVER_URL}/app/rest/agents/id:1/authorized"